# How to get the URL of a route without the route in Angular 8+

Tags: angular, routes

My full URL is `http://localhost:4200/recommendation` which I can get using `location.href`

However all I need is to know the URL I'm on without the route. So just `http://localhost:4200`

Is there a way of using the router in Angular to do this or will I need to split the string? If I need to split the string then how would I do so to just get the one part of the URL that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for might be `window.location.origin`, which will return the hostname with the HTTP protocol.

```js
// Please note that the snippet run in an IFrame, 
// so the url is not going to be stackoverflow.
console.log(window.location.origin)
```